# Need partial record from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables as shown in figure 1:

[image]

And I need this result:

[image]

I tried it with joins, but I am unable to get the needed result.

```
    SELECT 
   company_info.t_id, 
   company_info.company_name, 
   company_info.remark, 
   tender.company_selected, 
   company_info.company_document 
FROM 
   company_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tender 
ON company_info.t_id = tender.t_id;
```

**Note:** It is showing Company Document in both rows, but I need it only for the company which is selected. Please check the snapshot 2 for reference.

Comment: Apply the `first table left join second table` Try that

Comment: Can you show the query you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked

```
SELECT company_info.t_id, company_info.company_name, company_info.remark,
CASE WHEN tender.company_selected =company_info.company_name THEN tender.company_selected ELSE '' END,
CASE WHEN tender.company_selected =company_info.company_name THEN company_info.company_document ELSE '' END FROM 
company_info LEFT OUTER JOIN tender ON company_info.t_id = tender.t_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   company_info.t_id, 
   company_info.company_name, 
   company_info.remark, 
   tender.company_selected, 
   company_info.company_document 
FROM 
   company_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tender 
ON company_info.t_id = tender.t_id;
```

Comment: It is showing Company Document in both rows, but I need it only for the company which is selected. Please check the snapshot 2 for reference.

Comment: Then use this in the SELECT part: 

    **CASE
          WHEN tender.company_selected  = '' THEN ''
          ELSE company_info.company_document
       END** (this goes in place of **company_info.company_document** in my code above). Please note that I'm writing this from memory without actually checking the code, but you should be able to figure this out now.

Comment: I am not much familiar with sql, can you please give me exact query. I am trying for 3 hours and every thing is messed up in my mind. Thanks for response.

Comment: **SELECT 
   company_info.t_id, 
   company_info.company_name, 
   company_info.remark, 
   tender.company_selected, 
   company_info.company_document 
FROM 
   company_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tender 
ON company_info.t_id = tender.t_id;SELECT 
   company_info.t_id, 
   company_info.company_name, 
   company_info.remark, 
   tender.company_selected, 
   CASE WHEN tender.company_selected = '' THEN '' ELSE company_info.company_document END 
FROM 
   company_info 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tender 
ON company_info.t_id = tender.t_id;**

(if **= ''** doesn't work try **IS NULL** instead)

Answer (score 0):

A `left join` should do the trick:

```
SELECT    a.t_id a.company_name, a.remark, 
          b.company_selected, b.company_document
FROM      company_info a
LEFT JOIN tender b ON a.t_id = b.t_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you what you are looking for :

```
SELECT c.t_id,
       c.company_name,
       c.remark,
       IFNULL(t.company_selected,'') as company_selected, 
       CASE WHEN t.company_selected IS NULL THEN '' ELSE c.company_document END AS company_document
FROM company_info c LEFT JOIN
     tender t ON c.t_id=t.t_id AND c.company_name=t.company_selected
```

**Explanation:**

This query will do the following:

- selecting `t_id`,`comapany_name`,`remark` from company table.
- Selecting company name from tender table. If there is no record, this column will be empty.
- If there is no record in tender table, this column will be empty, otherwise, it will select `company_document` from company table.